# Prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty}{ \sqrt[n]{ \prod_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i+k)}} - k } = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, means

I accidentally discovered this equality, in which I can prove numerically using python.

### $$\lim_{k\to\infty}{ \sqrt[n]{ \prod_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i+k)}} - k } = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}}{n}$$

But I need to prove this equality in an algebraic way and I could not get anywhere. The right-hand side is nothing more than an arithmetic mean, while the left-hand side is a modification of the geometric mean.
I hope someone can help me at this point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume that $k$ is greater than twice $|x_1|+\ldots+|x_n|$ and also greater than twice $M=x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2$. Over the interval $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ we have
$$ e^x = 1+x+C(x)x^2, \qquad \log(1+x)=x+D(x)x^2 $$
with $|C(x)|,|D(x)|\leq 1$. It follows that

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\text{GM}(x_1+k,\ldots,x_n+k)&=&k\cdot \text{GM}\left(1+\tfrac{x_1}{k},\ldots,1+\tfrac{x_n}{k}\right)\\&=&k\exp\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{x_j}{k}\right)\right]\\&=&k\exp\left[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{x_j}{n}+\Theta\left(\frac{M}{nk^2}\right)\right]\\&=&k\left[1+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{x_j}{n}+\Theta\left(\frac{M}{nk^2}\right)\right]\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the claim is proved. It looks very reasonable also without a formal proof: the magnitude of the difference between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean is controlled by $\frac{\text{Var}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{\text{AM}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}$. A translation towards the right leaves the variance unchanged and increases the mean.

Comment: While the above is correct (+1 for last paragraph) the result is proved via algebra alone by multiplying with conjugate.

Comment: Seems excellent to me. Put everything together results in:
$$\begin{align*}
        \def \mysum {\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x_i}{n}}}
        \mysum &= \lim_{k\to\infty}{ k  \left[1 + \frac{1}{k}\mysum + \Theta\left(\frac{M}{nk^2}\right) \right] - k} \\
        &= \lim_{k\to\infty}{ \mysum + \Theta\left(\frac{M}{nk^2}\right)} \\
        &= \lim_{k\to\infty}{ \mysum} + \lim_{k\to\infty}{\Theta\left(\frac{M}{nk^2}\right)}, \qquad \text{where} \lim_{k\to\infty}{\Theta\left(\frac{M}{nk^2}\right)} \to 0\\
        &= \mysum\\
      \end{align*}$$
Then the equality is proven. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You could even get an interesting asymptotics considering $$y_n=\sqrt[n]{ \prod_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i+k)}}$$ $$ \log(y_n)=\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log\left({(x_i+k)}\right)=\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\log(k)+\log\left(1+\frac {x_i}k\right)\right)$$ Assuming that $x_1<x_2<\cdots < x_n \ll k$,  use the Taylor expansion of $\log\left(1+\frac {x_i}k\right)$. Then continuing with Taylor series
$$y_n=e^{\log(y_n)}\implies
y_n=k+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}+\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\right)^2-n\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i}{2n^2 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$ making
$$ \sqrt[n]{ \prod_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i+k)}} - k =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}+\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\right)^2-n\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i}{2n^2 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$

For example, using $n=10$, $k=1000$ and $x_i=p_i$, the approximation would give $\frac{2572671}{200000}\approx 12.8634$ while the exact calculation would lead to $\approx 12.8639$

Comment: @GustavoAle. For sure ! I just wanted to see what would be the asymptotics. Cheers.

Comment: At this point the equality is proven by applying the limit itself,$$\lim_{k\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{ \prod_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i+k)}} - k} = \lim_{k\to\infty}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}+\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\right)^2-n\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i}{2n^2 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}$$  where $$\lim_{k\to\infty}{\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\right)^2-n\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i}{2n^2 k}} + O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \to 0$$ remaining only $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your expression under limit can be written as $k(a-b) $ where $$a=\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{x_i}{k}\right)}, b=1$$ and further $a-b=(a^n-b^n) / c$ where $a, b$ tend to $1$ and $$c=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$$ tends to $n$ as $k\to\infty$. And $$a^n-b^n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{x_i}{k}\right)-1=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+o(1/k)$$ and thus $$k(a-b) =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+o(1)$$ and the desired limit as $k\to\infty$ is $\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I thought you did not notice that only the geometric series is contained inside the nth-root, because I was unable to proceed the algebra with your suggestion, then I just left your answer unvoted.

Comment: @GustavoAle: Ok I will add details of $a, b, c$. I was trying to avoid typing large expressions but it appears the readability of post decreased way too much in that process.

Answer (score 2):

You can also give an argument using L'Hopital's rule:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^n (x_i + k)} - k &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^n \left(\frac{x_i}{k} + 1\right)} - 1}{\frac{1}{k}} \\
&\overset{(H)}{=} \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{-x_i}{k^2} \cdot \prod_{j \ne i} \left(\frac{x_i}{k} + 1\right)}{\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n \left(\frac{x_i}{k} + 1\right)\right)^{1 - 1/n}}}{\frac{-1}{k^2}} \\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \cdot \prod_{j \ne i} \left(\frac{x_i}{k} + 1\right)}{\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n \left(\frac{x_i}{k} + 1\right)\right)^{1 - 1/n}} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i}{n}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\left[\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i+k)\right)^{1/n}-k\right]
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}k\left[\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{x_i}k\right)^{1/n}-1\right]\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{x_i}k\right)^{1/n}-1}{\log\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{x_i}k\right)^{1/n}\right)}\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac kn\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{x_i}k\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}\cdot\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\lim_{k\to\infty}k\log\left(1+\frac{x_i}k\right)\\[9pt]
&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i
\end{align}
$$